# argument types sent to getDeclaredMethod(String, Class[]) in java reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection, annotations

i have a method in a class like this:

```
public static void postEvents(List<RuleEvent> eventList) {
    for(RuleEvent event:eventList)
        if(canProcess(event))
            findListenerAndPost(event);
    }
```

and i want to access it using reflection like this:

```
Class partypes[] = new Class[1];
partypes[0] = List.class;    //does not find the method as it is of List<RuleEvent>
postMethod = cls.getMethod("postEvents", partypes);
```

so, how do I get the class object of `List<RuleEvent>`????

I already know the way of `((List<RuleEvent>) new ArrayList<RuleEvent>()).getClass()` but there should be a more direct way...

Comment: Works fine for me. Do you get an error? Due to type erasure there isn't a `List<RuleEvent>` at runtime.

Comment: i just dont find the method. it comes as null

Comment: Is `cls` the right class? Null?! You should get a `NoSuchMethodException` if the method doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't think using a `new ArrayList<RuleEvent>().getClass()` works either - first of all, since it returns an ArrayList.class rather than List.class, and second, because of type erasure, it still returns a raw ArrayList.class object.

Comment: sorry guys! I made huge blunder... The package used in class.forName() was wrong.

Comment: Still. Is there a possibility of handling generic types in reflection?

Comment: No, because at runtime, all the generic type information is erased. So the method signature in the JVM is actually postEvents(List).

Comment: but then we should have the argument types of those functions right?

Comment: @Piyush There is nothing besides `List` at runtime; see the [Type Erasure tutorial page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Not sure how else to say it, or how many others need to say the same thing.

Comment: ok I understand now. sry for being so slow. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you need is the following

```
cls.getMethod("postEvents", List.class).invoke(null, eventList);
```

The generic type is not required at runtime.